# setTimeOut on a redirect function to redirect twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, html

**Update** -- Im working on a simple function which after click redirects you to an external page with the product you choosed in a form. the thing is that I need to do first a redirect to a "thank you for your purchase" page and then redirect to the external... this is my code and how I tried to do it.

```
 function addToListAndRedirect(item_id){
var email = jQuery("[name='your-email']").val();
var amount = jQuery("[name='vinbrevet-contact-amount']").val();
var subscription = {
    ListIds: [
        "beeb2f48-5265-443e-960f-4f995d8c2942"
    ],  
    ConfirmationIssue: { IssueId: "cd081857-4f30-4da1-ab5c-a7883f62d99c" },       
    Contact: {
        Email: email
    }
}
window.location.href = "http://vinbrevet.se/success?items="+ item_id + ":" + amount;

jQuery.post("http://ui.admlo.se/Api/Subscriptions/c03a4119-f6a8-4d86-b34f-f16177ec7912", subscription).always(function() {
    function redirectToExternal(item_id, amount) {
    window.location.replace("https://www.systembolaget.se/dryckeslista?items="+item_id+":" + amount);
    }
});
```

}

and on /success

```
function redirectToExternal(item_id, amount) {
    window.location.replace("https://www.systembolaget.se/dryckeslista?items="+item_id+":" + amount);
    }

setTimeout("redirectToExternal()", 5000);
```

**now the redirection works great but I can't get the item_id and amount? should I duplicate the whole function also in /success?**

So is like this: you post your purchase go to "/success" page and after 5 seconds it will redirect to the external page with the item_id. Where Im doing it wrong?

Comment: Nothing after this line `window.location.href = "http://dryckesbrevet.se/success";` will get executed, because you told the browser to go to a new page and forget about this one. Surely that's obvious? If you want a second redirect, you have to put the code for that in the "success" page

Comment: this is not possible  as u have to redirect to other page in `http://dryckesbrevet.se/success` page and save item_id and amount in session and fetch in `http://dryckesbrevet.se/success`

Answer (score 1):

Your success page should take the product id in the url, and the second redirect script should be on the success page.

```
window.location.href = "http://dryckesbrevet.se/success";
```

The code below that won't run as you are now on a different page!

Try something like:

window.location.href = "http://dryckesbrevet.se/success?id="+product_id;

Then put your `setTimeout()` on the success page, grab the id and redirect!

Answer (score 1):

You can't *redirect two times*. As soon as you set `location.href` your browser will be moving to it and any further actions will not take effect.

You need to pass second redirect url to first page, and from first page make redirect after 5 seconds.

1. `location.href='http://dryckesbrevet.se/success&redirect='+encodeURIComponent("http://ui.admlo.se/Api/Subscriptions/c03a4119-f6a8-4d86-b34f-f16177ec7912")`
2. `success` page shows message
3. `success` page executes `setTimeout("redirectToExternal()", 5000);` to redirect to external page provided in `&redirect=???`.